# A strange type of complex root

Tags: polynomials, riemann-zeta

This function is related to the zeta function for $-7.$

Here is a function which has $2$ complex roots at $\frac{1}{2}$ which I find very strange.
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Roots+n%5E2%2F12+-+(7+n%5E4)%2F24+%2B+(7+n%5E6)%2F12+%2B+n%5E7%2F2+%2B+n%5E8%2F8

My intuition with complex roots is that they help solve equations like $x^2 +1=0$ which don't cross the $x$-axis.
Thus we can shift this function by a constant so that the roots become real.

It seems like there will only be one value where these roots become real. But it is not like a root with odd multiplicity where the function clearly has zero derivative near the imaginary points.

My question is, what is a simple example of a function with a root with these properties. And what shift to the function makes this root real?

Comment: It's not a coincidence that two roots have real part 1/2.  In fact, the roots of any polynomial with real coefficients will be symmetric across the real axis - if $p(z) = 0$ then $p(\bar{z}) = 0$.

Comment: More generally, $p(\bar{z}) = \overline{p(z)}$ (again, assuming $p(z)$ has real coeficients.)  Will leave this for you to check...

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time understanding your question.

> My intuition with complex roots is that they help solve equations like
>   x^2 +1=0 which don't cross the x axis.

The way complex numbers are defined is as numbers of the form $a+bi$ for $a$ (the "real" part) and $b$ (the "imaginary" part) are real, and $i$ is such that $i^2=-1$. This definition leads to complex numbers which *do* help with solving equations like $x^2+1=0$, but complex numbers are interesting for other reasons than just helping with solving polynomial equations. This is why we have a more general definition of complex numbers.

It's important to note that you can have a function with real *and* non-real roots. So the graph of a polynomial on the real line might cross the x-axis any number of times, and still have non-real roots. The function you provided is such an example.

> It seems like there will only be one value where these roots become
>   real. But it is not like a root with odd multiplicity where the
>   function clearly has zero derivative near the imaginary points.

I'm not quite sure what you mean here. The sense of the "multiplicity" of a root is the power of the binomial in the factored form. For example $x=2$ is a root of multiplicity of 3 and $x=4$ is a root of miltiplicity of 1 in the polynomial $f(x)=12(x-2)^3(x-4)$. What I suspect you might be observing is the fact that non-real roots of polynomials with real coefficients come in "complex-conjugate pairs". Meaning that if $a+bi$ (where $a$ and $b$ are real) is a root $f(a+bi)=0$, then $a-bi$ is a root $f(a-bi)=0$. This is true for any polynomial with real coefficients. Is this what you are referring to?

> And what shift to the function makes this root real?

I'm not sure that there is a general guidline on how shifting a polynomial by a constant will make a root with non-zero imaginary part into a real root. Shifting a polynomial by a constant would, in many cases, turn real roots into non-real roots.

One very noteworthy fact about complex numbers is that any polynomial with complex coefficients (which includes any polynomial with real coefficients) with degree $n>0$ has a complex root. A consequence is that any polynomial with complex or real coefficients $p(x)$ with degree $n>0$ can be written in the form $p(x)=c(x-a_1)(x-a_2)...(x-a_n)$ (where some of these roots $a_1,...,a_n$ might equal one another).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that if I write the equation in the form of products of it's roots. You can then remove the real roots, and the equation becomes 1/24 n^2 (n + 1)^2 (3 n^4 + 6 n^3 - n^2 - 4 n + 2). 
This let's me see where the complex roots come from.

The roots are actually quite regular, but looked strange

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the equation by $24$ to get whole numbers $$2 n^2-7 n^4+14 n^6+12 n^7+3 n^8=0$$we can factor $n^2$ and write
$$n^2(2 -7 n^2+14 n^4+12 n^5+3 n^6)=0$$ By inspection $n=-1$ is a root so
$$n^2(n+1)(2-2 n-5 n^2+5 n^3+9 n^4+3 n^5)=0$$ By inspection again $n=1$ is a root so
$$n^2(n+1)^2(2-4 n-n^2+6 n^3+3 n^4)=0$$

Now, consider
$$f(n)=2-4 n-n^2+6 n^3+3 n^4$$
$$f'(n)=-4-2n+18n^2+12n^3$$
By inspection, $n=-\frac 12$ is a root making
$$f'(n)=\left(n+\frac 12 \right)(-8+12 n+12 n^2)$$ So, the zeros of the derivative are
$$n_1=-\frac 12 \qquad n_2=\frac{1}{6} \left(-3-\sqrt{33}\right) \qquad n_3=\frac{1}{6} \left(-3+\sqrt{33}\right)$$
$$f(n_1)=\frac{51}{16}\qquad f(n_2)=\frac{2}{3} \qquad f(n_3)=\frac{2}{3}$$ So the quartic never intersects the $x$ axis and then no real roots to it. You will then have four complex roots conjugate by pairs.

Comment: I can shift the quartic that you describe to make it's roots real.  I don't see how to make these roots real in the degree 8 function

Comment: Is it possible to have roots of a polynomial (with real coefficients) that are never real under any constant shift of the function